# Centering two views horizontally under another view in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have 3 buttons, one full width button on top of two buttons of half width of the screen. Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_delete"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_save" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btn_delete"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_save"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The outcome is that the cancel button is getting pushed down instead of aligning on the line horizontally with the delete button.
[image]

After playing around it a little bit, in order to make the cancel button to align horizontally with the delete button, I had to add either of the of following to the cancel button.

```
app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn_delete"
```

or

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
```

Questions:

1. Why did the ConstraintLayout pushed down the cancel button instead of aligning it with the delete button? Why do I have to use the baseline or bias on the cancel button in order to make it aligned on the same line?
2. Besides using the baseline and the bias, are there any other ways to make the cancel button align with the delete button?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why did the ConstraintLayout pushed down the cancel button instead of
>   aligning it with the delete button? Why do I have to use the baseline
>   or bias on the cancel button in order to make it aligned on the same
>   line?

`cancel` button is pushed down because when you set following 2 constraints on the `cancel` button

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_save"
```

the `cancel` button is **vertically centered** between `save` button and the bottom of the parent layout.

Now **you might ask** that `delete` button also has same two constraints, then why did it not get pushed down like `cancel` button did?. **Reason is**, that you have set following constraint on `save` button

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_delete"
```

If you change it to

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_cancel"
```

`delete` button will be pushed down and `cancel` button will be aligned with `save` button.

If you change it to

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

you will get the following layout

[image]

Notice that, `delete` and `cancel` button now are **aligned in same way**. Reason is that now both `delete` and cancel button have following constraints

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_save"
```

Both buttons are **centered vertically** between the `save` button and bottom of the parent layout.

> Besides using the baseline and the bias, are there any other ways to
>   make the cancel button align with the delete button?

There are multiple ways to achieve your desired layout

One way to do it is to remove the

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

from both `cancel` and `delete` button and change

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_delete"
```

to

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

in `save` button layout.

This will give you following layout

[image]

This method works because removing `bottom constraint` makes both `cancel` and `delete` button to **not align vertically centered** in the space between `save` button and the bottom of the parent layout.

Answer (score 6):

Remove  `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` from `btn_cancel`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_delete"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_cancel"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btn_delete"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_save" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OR**

Remove 
`app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` for more details check `chainStyle` https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain

Comment: Cool, it works by removing app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" from the cancel button, could you explain why? The delete button has this but it didn't get pushed down.

Comment: Updated the answer,it's because of `chainStyle`